# Rails messaging system between users

Tags: ruby-on-rails

First of all, this is a very simple question but I don't know if I can explain it clearly. So, it might seem little bit confusing.

I am working on a messaging system between users in a social network site. I am using this messaging system: https://medium.com/@danamulder/tutorial-create-a-simple-messaging-system-on-rails-d9b94b0fbca1

This messaging system is very simple and this is what I needed but this system pass conversation id in the link to find the related conversation. But what I am trying to do is to pass receiver's id in the link, because this is user friendly and also, later on I might update system to use username in the link instead of id and also this is what Facebook does.

I am stuck here.
I have 2 tables. One of them is conversation and the other one messages.
This is conversation:

[image]

This is messsages:

[image]

And I have this in my controller to find conversation:

```
  before_action do
    @conversation = Conversation.find(params[:id])
  end
```

So, in id part if I receive conversation id, I can find the related conversation but as I said, I am trying to pass id of "user 2".

Thank you.

Comment: `Conversation.find` will try to find a conversation record by its id. If you want to find a conversation by a user id you'll need something like `Conversation.where(sender_id: params[:id])`. However, that will give you all of the conversations for that sender -- you'll still need another piece of information to figure out which of those conversations is applicable to the current request. How are you expecting to find a specific conversation given only a user id (unless users can only have a single conversation)?

Comment: users can only have 1 conversation. I tried using sender_id but this will work if user 2 created conversation. I also need to be able to check if id belongs to recipient_id, too.

Comment: maybe I should change table structure. I am trying to figure out another table structure now.

Comment: In that case the conversations table may be adding an unnecessary level of indirection. You could, perhaps, leave out that table and just associate the messages directly with the users (so each message would have a `sender_id` and a `receiver_id`). Then you would be looking up a user instead of a conversation for a user, and from the user you can get all the messages sent or received.

Comment: @neuronaut Yes, conversation table is unnecessary. I am doing as you said. But still there is a problem. As you said, I'll be looking up for up a user in receiver and sender, as well. But how can I check both and put them in a single instance variable? Because users should be able to see both received and sent messages in chronological order.

Comment: I'd recommend adding a `scope` to your `User` model. Maybe something like this: `scope :all_messages, -> (id) {where('sender_id = ? OR receiver_id = ?', id, id).order('created_at desc')}`. Use the scope like this: `User.all_messages(params[:user_id])`

Comment: @neuronaut I am changing the messaging system and I will use this scope. I will let you know. Thank you.

Comment: What are you using for your database viewer? It looks great!

Comment: @RichPeck I am using RubyMine IDE. It has many features like database, VCS etc.. Amazing product.